# LeakCanary: Make detection faster?

Tags: android, leakcanary

When I use LeakCanary, the "Your activity leaked!" happens 1 or 2 minutes after I closed it. This is not so good, because I would have to wait long to see if the fix worked or not.

I do not know how or when the garbage collector works. So, the activity may still be in memory after it is closed for a while, if the system memory is sufficient. Can I make the GC to delete the activity as soon as I closed it whether the system memory is sufficient or not in the debug mode, and tell LeakCanary to detect leaks fast?